# Using AWS for a single web and database server

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability

I need to set up a public-facing web server and a private database server in AWS.  So that I can allow higher availability - is it okay that I have my public subnet in one AZ hosting my web server and another (so duplicate) WebServer in a different AZ?  The same principle would apply to database server configuration.  Essentially, Zone-A would host WebServer, Zone-B would host WebServer-copy. Zone-B would host DatabaseServer, Zone-A would host Database-copy.  Is this architecture a good practice?

If yes, does this configuration mean site files and database files are duplicated on each AZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's *basically* how you setup high availability on AWS. I would recommend using RDS for the database which will manage multi-az deployments for you automatically. Managing the data replication manually can be a real challenge.

I would also recommend looking into Elastic Beanstalk which will manage distributing the traffic across multiple zones, deploying and updating your application across multiple zones, and all the details that go along with that. I would not recommend diving straight in and trying to do all this manually in EC2 if you are new to AWS.